# Find distribution of $\frac{X}{X+Y}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I need to find distribution of $G=\frac{X}{X+Y}$ and $H=X-Y$ where $X$,$Y$~$Exp(1)$ and are independent. I have found a solution somewhere here, but it used methods I haven't got a chance to learn yet. Here is my attempt. I will be very glad for checking it.
So knowing that $X,Y$ are independent, we know that density of $W=(X,Y)$ if product of densities of $X$ and $Y$. So $g(x,y)=e^{-x-y}$ for $x,y>0$ and zero otherwise. 
Now:
$$P(G<t)=P((X,Y):\frac{X}{X+Y}<t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{\frac{x}{t}-x}^{\infty}e^{-x-y}dydx=...$$ and calculate it. Similarly I want to calculate H. Is it ok?

Comment: It is okay. Test it by finding the integral. The distribution of $G$ will turn out to be uniform on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Indeed I came up with uniform, thanks for confirmation :) Would you take a look at (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2293509/prove-that-sqrtx2y2-and-fracyx-are-independent) also? I will be very obliged.