# Prove that $\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ and $\frac{Y}{X}$ are independent

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given $X,Y$~$N(0,1)$independent so (X,Y) has density $\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}$I need to prove that $S=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ and $R=\frac{Y}{X}$ are independent. I wanted to calculate distribution of $S$ and $R$ and to show that its product is in fact (S,R). Using polar cordinates:
$$P(S<t)=P(X^2+Y^2<t^2)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{t}re^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}drd\alpha$$ So we can clearly calculate that one. But I have a problem with $R$.
$$P(R<t)=P(\frac{Y}{X}<t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{tx}\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}dxdy$$ How should I parametrize it? Using polar cordinates doesn't seems to work.

Comment: The ratio of two normal variables has a Cauchy distribution.

Comment: It might be easier to compute the joint CDF of $S^2, R$ directly and then show that it factors into a product of two valid CDF's depending only on $S^2$ and $R$. Then, note $S^2$ is independent of $R$ iff $S$ is independent of $R$.

Comment: Knowing that (X,Y) independent $\iff$ ((f(X),g(Y)) independent (for $f,g$ deterministic bijections),use Box-Muller's transform (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) and the fact that $Y/X=$atan$(\Theta)$ where $\Theta$ is the polar angle of $(X,Y)$.

Comment: In polar coördinates we have $\langle X,Y\rangle=\langle r\cos\phi, r\sin\phi\rangle$. If  $r$ and $\phi$ are independent (this can be shown, and I advice you to do that) then "automatically" (i.e. not difficult to prove) $f(r)$ and $g(\phi)$ are independent for measurable functions $f,g$. This can be applied since $\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}=r$ and $Y/X=\tan\phi$.

Answer (score 1):

The pdfs for $R$ and $S$ are given by:

$$f_R(r) = {1 \over \pi} \frac{1}{1+r^2}, \quad r \in \mathbb{R}$$
$$f_S(s) = se^{-{1 \over 2} s^2}, \quad s \geq 0.$$

The joint pdf is given by

$$f_{R,S}(r,s) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \iint_\mathbb{R^2} dxdy \ e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2} \delta(y/x -r )\delta(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-s) $$

Go to polar coordinates:

$$...=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}d\theta \int_0^\infty d\rho \ \rho e^{-\rho^2/2}  \delta(\tan \theta -r) \delta(\rho-s).$$

These seperate:

$$= se^{-s^2/2} \ \left[ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \delta (\tan \theta -r) \right].$$

It remains to show that the bracket is the pdf for $R$. Using delta function properties:

$$\delta (\tan \theta -r) =\sum_i \frac{\delta(\theta - \theta_i)}{|\cos^2 \theta_i|}$$

with $\tan \theta_i =r$. There are two such roots on the interval $[0,2\pi]$ with the same weight, namely

$$\frac{1}{|\cos^2 \theta_i|} = \frac{1}{1+r^2},$$

therefore the result is

$$f_{R,S}(r,s)  = \left[ se^{-s^2/2} \right] \ \left[{1 \over \pi} \frac{1}{1+r^2}\right] = f_S(s) f_R(r), \quad s\geq 0, r\in \mathbb{R}.$$

Therefore $R$ and $S$ are independent.